# What's wrong with this authorization exchange?

Tags: mediawiki, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've set up a MediaWiki server on an Azure website with the [PluggableAuth](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PluggableAuth) and [OpenID Connect](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID_Connect) extensions. The latter uses the [PHP OpenID Connect Basic Client](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) library. I am an administrator in the Azure AD domain `example.com`, wherein I've created an application with App ID URI, sign-on URL and reply URL all set to `https://wiki.azurewebsites.net/`. When I navigate to the wiki, I observe the following behavior (cookie values omitted for now):

1. **Client** Request

   `GET https://wiki.azurewebsites.net/ HTTP/1.1`
2. **RP** Request

   `GET https://login.windows.net/example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`
3. **IP** Response

   *(some response)*
4. **RP** Response

   `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
   Location: https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.azurewebsites.net%2F&client_id={client_id}&nonce={nonce}&state={state}`
5. **Client** Request

   *(follows redirect)*
6. **IP** Response

   `HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Location: https://wiki.azurewebsites.net/?code={code}&state={state}&session_state={session_state}`
7. **Client** Request

   *(follows redirect)*
8. **RP** Request *(also repeats #2 & #3)*

   `POST https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token
   grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.azurewebsites.net%2F&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}`
9. **IP** Response

   (As interpreted by MediaWiki; I don't have the full response logged at this time)

   **`AADSTS50001: Resource identifier is not provided.`**

Note that if I change the OpenID PHP client to provide the 'resource' parameter in step 8, I get the following error response from AAD instead:

8. **RP** Request

   `POST https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token
   grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.azurewebsites.net%2F&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.azurewebsites.net%2F&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}`
9. **IP** Response

   **`AADSTS90027: The client '{client_id}' and resource 'https://wiki.azurewebsites.net/' identify the same application.`**

   [(This has come up before.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212950/stuck-between-two-errors-in-an-azure-oauth2-token-request)

### Update

I've made some progress based on @jricher's suggestions, but after working through several more errors I've hit one that I can't figure out. Once this is all done I'll submit pull requests to the affected libraries.

Here's what I've done:

- I've added a second application to the `example.com` Azure AD domain, with the App ID URI set to `mediawiki://wiki.azurewebsites.net/`, as **a dummy "resource"**. I also granted the `https://wiki.azurewebsites.net/` application delegated access to this new application.
- Passing in the dummy application's URI as **the `resource` parameter** in step #8, I'm now getting back the access, refresh, and ID tokens in #9!
- The OpenID Connect library requires that the ID token be signed, but while Azure AD signs the access token it doesn't sign the ID token. It comes with the following properties: `{"typ":"JWT","alg":"none"}`. So I had to modify the library to allow the caller to specify that **unsigned ID tokens are considered "verified"**. Grrr.
- Okay, next it turns out that the claims can't be verified because the OpenID Provider URL I specified and the issuer URL returned in the token are different. (Seriously?!) So, **the provider has to be specified as `https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/`**, and then that works.
- Next, I found that I hadn't **run the MediaWiki DB upgrade script for the OpenID Connect extension** yet. Thankfully that was a quick fix.
- After that, I am now left with (what I hope is) the final problem of **trying to get the user info from AAD's OpenID Connect UserInfo endpoint.** I'll give that its own section.

### Can't get the user info [Updated]

This is where I am stuck now. After step #9, following one or two intermediate requests to get metadata and keys for verifying the token, the following occurs:

10. **RP** Request:

    *(Updated to use GET with `Authorization: Bearer` header, per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) and [the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest).)*

    `GET https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/openid/userinfo
    Authorization: Bearer {access_token}`
11. **IP** Response:

    **`400 Bad Request
    AADSTS50063: Credential parsing failed. AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint.`**

    *(If I change #10 to be either a POST request, with `access_token` in the body, or a GET request with `access_token` in the query string, AAD returns the error: `AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. UserInfo token is not valid.` The same occurs if I use the value of the `id_token` in place of the `access_token` value that I received.)*

Help?

### Update

I'm still hoping someone can shed light on the final issue (the UserInfo endpoint not accepting the bearer token), but I may split that out into a separate question. In the meantime, I'm adding some workarounds to the libraries (PRs coming soon) so that the claims which are already being returned in the bearer token can be used instead of making the call to the UserInfo endpoint. Many thanks to everyone who's helped out with this.

There's also a nagging part of me that wonders if the whole thing would not have been simpler with the OpenID Connect Basic Profile. I assume there's a reason why that was not implemented by the MediaWiki extension.

### Update 2

I just came across [a new post from Vittorio Bertocci](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/INTRODUCING-ADAL-JS-V1/) that includes this helpful hint:

> ...in this request the application is asking for a token for itself! In Azure AD this is possible only if the requested token is an id_token...

This suggests that just changing the token request type in step 8 from `authorization_code` to `id_token` could remove the need for the non-standard `resource` parameter and also make the ugly second AAD application unnecessary. Still a hack, but it feels like much less of one.

Comment: "400 Bad Request" - It's possible that MicroSoft is looking for the request to be made as a POST and not as a GET. You'll need to modify the PHP lib to change this.

Comment: Okay, more than interesting - it would be consistent with all the other requests. :)

Comment: I've so far tried changing it to a GET with an `Authorization: Bearer` header, as [recommended by the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest) and [shown in MSDN ("Use the Access Token to Access the Resource")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx). No luck though - I get these two errors: `AADSTS50063: Credential parsing failed. AADSTS90010: JWT tokens cannot be used with the UserInfo endpoint.` I'll try POST next.

Comment: Actually, I should probably be trying to figure out how to send a bearer token and what the difference is between that and the access token that I was trying to send. Oh joy, more standards reading. :P

Comment: So, now I understand what makes a token a bearer token (simply that it can be used without any other proof of identity by any "bearer"), and I've verified (per [the RFC, section 4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-4)) that I am in fact getting a bearer token from Azure AD. The problem I'm left with is that **AAD is unwilling to accept a JWT token at the UserInfo endpoint?!?**

Comment: I haven't figured out what could be wrong with sending a JWT token there. Any ideas? I'm going to try making step #10 a POST request just to eliminate that possibility, but the error code I'm getting seems to suggest it won't help.

Comment: In the case of both a POST request and a GET request with the `access_token` query parameter, AAD returns the error: **`AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. UserInfo token is not valid.`**

Comment: Did you ever get this working? By any chance could you post your config. I can't even get as far as you have.

Comment: I did not, sorry -- we are currently wiki-less. :( I do know that Microsoft recently made some significant updates to their protocol support to be more compliant with the standard. You might want to post a new question with your specific situation.

Comment: FYI, I almost have this working:
https://github.com/CyberNinjas/MW-OpenIdConnect

User is authenticated and added to the users table. For some reason though, the session isn't established and I'm not seeing any errors as to why.

Comment: Correction, I have it working. I was using REL1_27 of MediaWiki which apparently isn't stable. Everything works fine with my updated code if I put in in REL1_26.

Comment: That's great to hear @Doug! When I have a chance to get back to this I'll definitely review your code.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but just upgraded to REL1_27 and trying to do the same (mediawiki on a VM in Azure talking to AAD). Any advice?

Comment: In nowadays , 2019, some news, there are a simple "plug and play" solution?

Answer (score 5):

Justin is right. For authorization code grant flow, your must specify the resource parameter in either the authorization request or the token request.

Use &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F to get an access token for the Azure AD Graph API.

Use &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F to get a token for the Azure Service Management APIs.

...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide any insight into why the last step (#10, RP calling the `/openid/userinfo` endpoint) is failing? That's not the Graph API, is it? Is there a resource value for that?

Comment: It isn't. Instead of the access token use the id_token that you received with the authorize response - and let me know if it works.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Same result as with the `access_token`.

Comment: I think if you specify scope=openid on the authorize request, that should allow you to get back an id_token and an access token that you can use to call the userinfo endpoint, without specifying a resource.  Let me know if that works...

Comment: Yeah this was something I didn't realize until it hit me in the head: Azure sends the id_token out early in the grant flow, no need to do an additional request. The unpacked id token had what I needed anyway, email and a unique identifier as I recall (it's been a few months ago now)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's implementation of OpenID Connect (and OAuth2) has a known bug where it requires the `resource` parameter to be sent by the client. This is an MS-specific parameter and requiring it unfortunately breaks compatibility with pretty much every major OAuth2 and OpenID Connect library out there. I know that MS is aware of the issue (I've been attempting to do interoperability testing with their team for quite a while now), but I don't know of any plans to fix the problem.

So in the mean time, your only real path is to hack your client software so that it sends a `resource` parameter that the AS will accept. It looks like you managed to make it send the parameter, but didn't send a value that it liked.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on what that value is supposed to be?

Comment: It's meant to represent the protected resource, so it's somehow related to that. I don't know what value that would be to access the identity API, which is usually hosted on the server itself.

Comment: Hm. I might try creating two separate applications then - I'm thinking to emulate the flow described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Comment: I updated my answer with the result of trying that approach. I've almost got it, just have to get the AAD UserInfo endpoint to work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad someone agrees with my thoughts, too. I really wish the `resource` parameter is optional :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had issues getting this running on Azure, even though I got something working locally. Since I was trying to setup a private wiki anyway, I ended up enabling Azure AD protection for the whole site by turning on:

```
All Settings -> Features -> Authentication / Authorization
```

From within the website in https://portal.azure.com

This made it so you had to authenticate to Azure-AD before you saw any page of the site. Once you were authenticated a bunch of HTTP Headers are set for the application with your username, including REMOTE_USER. As a result I used the following plugin to automatically log the already authenticated user into Azure:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Auth_remoteuser

Comment: I'm following in your footsteps here, trying to figure out the same. Private wiki (hosted on a VM in Azure) talking to Azure AD. Your MS-OpenIdConnect link is dead. Can you republish?

Comment: @LarrySilverman I'm sorry,  I appear to no longer have that code. I'm updating my answer to only reference the Auth_remoteuser.