# Azure AD OAuth Access Token Request ::: 400 - Bad Request

Tags: php, azure, oauth, office365

I have a php web app built upon Laravel 5 / Socialite, where I am trying to implement a SSO solution with windows azure AD OAuth flow, but I am getting a generic "**400 Bad Request Error**" on the second OAuth request for an Access Token.
The first request to the office 365 authorize URL is successful and returns an authorization code to my app, but when I try to get a user access token it fails.

I have checked and rechecked my request and it appears correct as much as I can tell:

```
POST https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token
```

HEADERS

```
Host:login.windows.net
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: wTrack/.001
Date: Thu, 21 May 2015 02:48:43 GMT
```

BODY

```
client_id=1ad9f025-dfaf-4cb7-a9ff-29ea619bab44&
client_secret=<secret>&
code=<code>&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwtrack.dev%2Flogin%2Fmicrosoft&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I have been looking at this for quite some time.  Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a rule response with status 400 contains a JSON with explanatory message. Could you please check it and post it if it exists?

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Igor.  Once I knew the JSON information was there, I dug around until I found it :)  Turns out I was getting the error because I was not including the `resource` parameter in the body of the POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `redirect_uri` is the same as the one you used for the authorization code request. Also, you might try adding the `resource` parameter in your request body.

Comment: The issue was that I wasn't including the `resource` parameter in the POST body (even though the documentation says its optional).  I did not find this as the Socialite/Guzzle library doesn't include the relevant error in their generic error logs until exposed through catch.  I now getting another error: `AADSTS90027: The client '...' and resource '...' identify the same application`  Which is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212950/stuck-between-two-errors-in-an-azure-oauth2-token-request), but to me doesn't seem like a very good solution.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648978/azure-ad-oauth2-access-token-request-error-400-bad-request