# Azure AD OAuth2 Access Token Request Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

My WPF desktop application (C#) is attempting to read the user's Outlook emails through the Microsoft Graph API. I am stuck in the authentication process; I've already received an authentication code and now I'm trying to get an access token from Azure but keep getting a HTTP 400 error code when sending out the request for the *access token*:

```
/**** Auth Code Retrieval ****/
string authCodeUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";
authCodeUrl += "?client_id" = clientId;
authCodeUrl += "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
authCodeUrl += "&response_type=code";
authCodeUrl += "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F";
Process.start(authUrl); // User logs in, we get the auth code after login
string code = "......"; // Hidden for this post

/**** Access Token Retrieval ****/
string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"
string content = "grant_type=authorization_code";
content += "&client_id=" + clientId;
content += "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F";
content += "&code=" + code;
content += "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
try 
{
  using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // This throws exception
}
catch (Exception error) // This catches the exception
{
  Console.WriteLine(error.Message); // Outputs 400, bad request
}
```

The above is the code used to retrieve the auth code followed by the attempt to retrieve the access token. We do not have a client_secret because secrets are only for Web applications and this is a native desktop WPF application. I have read that this isn't an issue though. I have followed many tutorials and official docs online, mainly [the official Graph authorization doc](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization) and I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the request and I found the full error message: *The user or administrator has not consented to use the application*. I googled this message for a bit and found some stack articles and github issue threads that lead me to the solution: my request had been using "common", in the base URL, as the tenant ID when actually I needed to use my Azure tenant ID which I acquired through this [answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29635598/5348646). My new base URL for the authentication requests now looks like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize
```

where "xxxx-....xxx" would be replaced by your Azure tenant id!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a client secret, then you need to configure your tenant to support implicit grant flow. You can follow the directions from [this](http://simonjaeger.com/microsoft-graph-authentication-with-azure-ad/) blog post to perform / validate the configuration. This requires using the Azure management portal to download, modify the app manifest, and upload it.

Alternatively, and possibly a better strategy, is to switch your code over to using the [converged v2.0 authentication endpoints](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth). It allows management of your application using the [new app registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) and nicely supports implicit flow and dynamic scopes. You can find more information about the actual authentication flow [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/). It isn't far from what you are doing now and requires only a few small tweaks.

If you are still having issues after this, please reach out again. A fiddler / network trace would be very helpful. Also, the detailed message inside the exception would also be very helpful.

Comment: Can you provide the full 400 error message that you get back please (or as Robert says, a full fiddler trace).  Also are you sure that your app is registered as a native client (or public client) rather than a web app?  Native/public clients to not require a secret to redeem the code for an access token.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses! Fiddler helped me resolve the 400 error issue - it turned out that my authorization code had expired. I am now facing a new issue where the access token response isn't a json object containing the access token (like I expected) but is an html document. Here is the fiddler trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9w2-YCX6qYvZmxXdERjWDJsamM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That call appears to be a POST to the /authorize endpoint. You should be doing a POST to the /token endpoint to change an authorization code into an access token.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that is trivial mistake thanks, the real error is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9w2-YCX6qYvSm5jUzZicFJpMmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've been following the solution to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775287/oauth2-with-azure-ad-not-getting-user-consent

But I'm still getting the 400 error, I commented on the approved answer.

Comment: Okay so I fixed the issue, I was sending my requests with "common" as the tenant ID when I really needed to substitute that with my actual tenant id!