# 502.3 when calling AcquireTokenAsync in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm encountering a problem. I am using Microsoft Graph to get the current logged in user via `OnBehalfOfMsGraphAuthenticationProvider.cs` as seen in the following [solution](https://github.com/juunas11/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-sample-aspnetcore).

This has been working flawlessly, but I have been doing some refactoring, and suddenly I get an error when trying to execute my `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync()` method.

```
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request) {
    var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    //Get the access token used to call this API
    string token = await httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    //We are passing an *assertion* to Azure AD about the current user
    //Here we specify that assertion's type, that is a JWT Bearer token
    string assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

    //User name is needed here only for ADAL, it is not passed to AAD
    //ADAL uses it to find a token in the cache if available
    var user = httpContext.User;
    string userName =
        user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value ?? user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;

    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token, assertionType, userName);

    //Construct the token cache
    var cache = new DistributedTokenCache(user, _distributedCache,
        _loggerFactory, _dataProtectionProvider);

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] +
        _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"], true, cache);

    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"],
        (string) _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"]);

    //Acquire access token
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential, userAssertion); //This is where it crashes

    //Set the authentication header
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(result.AccessTokenType, result.AccessToken);
}
```

I am calling it from my `OrdersController`:

```
// POST: api/Orders
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] OrderDTO order) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var graphUser = await this.graphApiService.GetUserProfileAsync();
```

The refactoring has consisted of dividing my solution into two class library projects and one web project - the latter has the controllers and the React app. `GraphAPiClient` and the provider are located in the Core library like this:

[Screenshot of architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YscBG.png)

Comment: May be this is authentication issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/38754821/10634638

Comment: What is the output of `_configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] +
        _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: I have checked, and the output is correct. They both correspond with the correct GUIDs (I don't want to type them out because of security reasons).

Comment: @bestinamir Thank you for your answer! This is not a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com, however - when this problem arises, I have already done that call successfully, and now I want to call Graph API using the token I got. This has worked before - the thing that puzzles me is the strange error I get.

Comment: The authority shouldn't be two GUIDs, it should be a URI to the issuer of the token. eg. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thank you for your reply! However, when my problem arises I have already done a successful call to login.microsoftonline.com. The flow, as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) is the following:

1. Register your app with Azure AD.
2. Get authorization.
3. Get an access token.
4. Call Microsoft Graph with the access token.
5. Use a refresh token to get a new access token.

The call using the GUIDs belong to #4, and makes a call to "https://graph.microsoft.com". More [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet).

Comment: This is the line I was asking about `var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] +
        _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"], true, cache);`. T

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Yes, the instance is indeed "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" while the tenantid is a GUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that the problem appeared when I upgraded the package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory from v3.19.8 to v4.4.1. For some reason, no versions above v3.19.8 work with my code, causing it to crash when I try to make the call to https://graph.microsoft.com, but as soon as I downgraded the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -2):

Try using AcquireToken instead of AcquireTokenAsync

```
azureAuthenticationContext.AcquireToken
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, AuthenticationContext does not contain a definition for AcquireToken. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Ok, My bad.. AcquireToken is in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory(V2.28.3.860) used in .NET framework projects.                                                                                                   Here is the code that works in .NET Core `azureAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cred).Result`. Try installing this package "Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Version 4.4.1"

Comment: Thank you, but this is exactly what I have been doing so far. Unfortunately, it doesn't work!